# Character to bits with SIMD (and substrings)

Tags: sse, simd, avx

I am learning little by little SIMD programming, and I've devised a (seemingly) simple problem that I hope I can speed-up using SIMD (AVX, at the moment I have access only to AVX CPUs).

I have a long string constituted by an alphabet of `2^k` characters (for instance `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`), and I'd like to:

- generate all substrings of a given length `substringlength`
- convert all the substrings in bits

The substrings are just sequences of characters from the input string:

```
012301230123012301230123012301233012301301230123123213012301230 

substringlength = 6;

string    bits
------+--+-----------------
012301 -> 01 00 11 10 01 00
123012 -> 10 01 00 11 10 01
230123 -> 11 10 01 00 11 10
301230 -> 00 11 10 01 00 11
...
```

My question is due to my inexperience with SIMD (I've only read "Modern x86 Assembly Language Programming", by Kusswurm):

> Is this a task where SIMD could help?

**Edit**: for simplicity, let's just assume `k = 2`, and so the ASCII numbers will be just `'0'..'3'`.

## Iteration 1

Reading the comments and playing around I've come to these realizations. I can convert the the ASCII into values, and as suggested, multiply-add adjacent bytes:

```
        // SIMD 128-bit registers, apparently I cannot use AVX ones directly (some operations are AVX2 or AVX-512)
        __m128i sse, val, adj, res;
        auto mask = _mm_set_epi8(1, 1<<4, 1, 1<<4, 1, 1<<4, 1, 1<<4, 1, 1<<4, 1, 1<<4, 1, 1<<4, 1, 1<<4);
        auto zero = _mm_set_epi8('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
                                 '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0');

        // Load ascii values
        sse = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) s.data());

        // Convert to integer values
        val = _mm_sub_epi8(sse[0], zero);

        // Multiply with mask byte by byte (aka SHL second bytes of val) and sum
        adj = _mm_maddubs_epi16(val, mask);
```

An idea of what it does, to people learning like me, is given here (I will need more 128-bits to encode one substring, **ascii is in hex**):

```
bytes   15   14   13   12   11   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0

ascii   30   31   30   31   30   31   30   31   30   31   30   31   30   31   30   31

_mm_sub_epi8:

value    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1

_mm_maddubs_epi16:

value    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1
         *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *    *
mask     1    4    1    4    1    4    1    4    1    4    1    4    1    4    1    4
            +         +         +         +         +         +         +         +
        |        |         |         |         |         |         |         |        |
(16-bits)
bits     ....0100  ....0100  ....0100  ....0100  ....0100  ....0100  ....0100 ....0100
```

**In other words** the first 4 bits are correct, encoding 2 ascii chars, **if I understand correctly** what `_mm_maddubs_epi16` did to my values, which I am not sure at all!

Now I'd need some sort of "*shift-or*" of adjacent bytes, something like `_mm_maddubs_epi16` that shifts left the first, and ORs with the second argument, producing an 8-bit or 16-bit value:

```
(16-bits)
bits     ....0100  ....0100  ....0100  ....0100  ....0100  ....0100  ....0100 ....0100
         | shl 4          |  | shl 4          |  | shl 4          |  | shl 4         |
         0100....  ....0100  0100....  ....0100  0100....  ....0100  0100.... ....0100
                 OR                 OR                  OR                  OR
             ....01000100      ....01000100         ....01000100       ....01000100
```

However, I cannot see how `_mm_bslli_si128` could help me here, or if there is a smarter way to do this. Maybe even this "horizontal" approach is foolish, and I have to rethink it.

Any hint is welcome!

Comment: Do you need the intermediate step of having a string of (ASCII?) characters, or do you really just want to generate all permutations of k-bit chunks packed together?  Or wait, you're not *generating* these substrings, but rather *extracting* them from a given input string, like with a sliding window?

Comment: You'll probably need different code for each possible `k` to do this efficiently, with custom shuffles and bit-shift counts for packing bits together across bytes.  `pmaddubsw` with a vector of `{1, 1<<k, 1, 1<<k, ...}` might work as a way to left-shift and combine (via adding) data from adjacent bytes, after a `psubb` or `pand` to turn ASCII codes into integers.

Comment: For `k = 8`, `[p]alignr` should be helpful in a loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've edited by question by using just `k=2` and adding some code. I have doubts it works as I intended, though.

Comment: You want `mask = 4 = 1<<2`, not `1<<4`.  And BTW, you can express that 16-bit pattern as `_mm_set1_epi16(0x41)`.  Similarly, `_mm_set1_epi8('0')`.  Using `maddubs` to left shift and pack bits together is a good idea, but you probably to feed a pair of mad result vectors to `_mm_packus_epi16` to get down to 8-bit elements.  Then maybe right-shift and OR, then packus again.  (For a right shift, `_mm_srli_epu16` should work).